# Xcode 8 project build successful but UI test build failing

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

I am working on a Xcode8.3.3 iOS10.3 compatible project and it has some UI tests (I had written them) associated with it which were building successfully and passing until the recent dependency pod library update, in spite of  warnings in the warnings tab.However, after updating my dependent pod library to newer version, the build for UI tests are failing showing same warnings that were present already as "reason", but project build is passing. Could it be due to some misconfiguration(I did not make any configuration changes though other than incrementing pod library version) or some error check set to strict or something else? No hint on what could be the issue. Do suggest.

(Note: there is no specific code that I think will be required as this is a problem with only UI tests not building and suggestions of build config -- zero code changes compared to UI tests that were building earlier -- if required I am ready to show, let me know what I have to show).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a newbie to Xcode. It seems I somehow clicked on disable tests option which comes when we try to run tests from the fifth icon in left pane and select test to run.Hence, the build was failing and it never notified me I had disabled tests.Now I have found this and enabled this option and it's working fine.

As you see this has nothing to do with code and thanks for not hinting out this could be an issue :) and all your kind down votes.